# Got error when tried to restore postgresql data from docker in windows

Tags: django, postgresql, docker-compose

i'm using windows and got this error when tried to restore PostgreSQL data from docker. The problem seem like because docker can't find that file but there is file exist in postgresql_backups folder. I tried searching but no result, can anyone help? (by the way, macos seem run fine without problem)
Here is the error:

```
PS D:\test> docker-compose exec postgresql restore demo.sql.gz

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: no such file or directory: unknown
```

Here is my postgresql config in docker-compose.yml:

```
postgresql:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/postgresql/Dockerfile
    image: testuser_postgresql
    volumes:
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgresql_backups:/backups:delegated
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=testuser
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

Comment: Here is the error:
PS D:\test> docker-compose exec postgresql restore demo.sql.gz

OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: no such file or directory: unknown

Comment: please post the error that you had, edit in your question don't post in comment section

Comment: also post the content of your docker-compose.yml file so we can see how you handle the paths

Comment: i updated it, @LinhNguyen